# Carousel not starting automatically but after click it work

Tags: bootstrap-4, carousel

I am using bootstrap4 and carousel. But carousel does not start automatically and after clicking in image its works as desired.

[my website](https://www.arihantmandal.com)

Comment: Your question needs to contained in your question. Please do not add anyone to go to any random site. Also, we're not a website debugging service.